# using included method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include

Suppose I have this

```
module Command
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        @path ||= File.join("#{file_path}", "some_file")
      end

      def file_path
        File.expand_path("some_other_file")
      end
...
```

When the module is included, I get `undefined local variable or method file_path`. So is there a way, to make the `file_path` method be recognized when the module is included ? (of course without putting `file_path` in the `included` method)

Comment: [`Module#included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-included) didn't take block.. Where you found the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method `file_path`,in the method `included`, `do..end` block. That means with scope is set as `Command` class. But `file_path` is the instance_method,so `Command.file_path` is throwing an legitimate error. You have to call the method `file_path`,on the instance of the class which is including the `Command` module. One example to illustrate this -

```
module A
    def self.included(mod)
        p foo
    end
    def foo
        2
    end
end

class B
    include A
end

# `included': undefined local variable or method `foo' for A:Module (NameError)
```

The error is coming because inside the method `included` self is `A`. `A` has no class method named as `foo`,so the error comes out. Now to fix it we should call it as below:

```
module A
    def self.included(mod)
        p mod.new.foo
    end
    def foo
        2
    end
end

class B
    include A
end

# >> 2
```

Comment: ok thanks interesting ! but should I prefer the response of @newben. because module `Command` is included inside some class Generator < Initializer, where `Initializer` has an `initialize(param1,param2)` method. So following your method I get a legitimate ` wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`... ?

Comment: @user1611830 Whichever fits good to you.. Because I don't know internal code you are having. I just gave you hints,how to move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

module Command
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

```
  def self.extended(klass)
    @path ||= File.join("#{klass.file_path}", "some_file")
  end

  def file_path
    File.expand_path("some_other_file")
  end
```

and then extend your module where you call it !